# Why is the result of UInt64.max.formatted(.number) wrong in iOS 16.7 and macOS 13.6

Tags: swift, foundation

I found `UInt64.max.formatted(.number)` and `UInt.max.formatted(.number)` return wrong value in iOS 16.7 and macOS 13.6.

- Expected: `18,446,744,073,709,551,615` (= 2^64-1)
- Actual: `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` (= 2^63-1)

macOS 14.0 (and iOS 17.0.1 on iPhone Simulator) returns correct value.

- `UInt64.max.formatted(.number)` → `18,446,744,073,709,551,615`
- `UInt.max.formatted(.number)` → `18,446,744,073,709,551,615`

Is it a bug of `Foundation.framework` in iOS 16 and macOS 13? Or is there a problem with my code?

I didn't see any mention about this changes in iOS 17 release notes.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-17-release-notes

(2023-10-29 Added) `NumberFormatter#string(from:)` also returns different value between macOS 14.0 and macOS 13.6.

```swift
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
print("UInt64.max: " + formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: UInt64.max))!)
```

- `18446744073709551615` in macOS 14.0 and iOS 17.0.1 on iPhone Simulator
- `-1` in macOS 13.6 and iOS 16.7 on iPhone 14

##### Source code:

```swift
print("UInt64.max.formatted(.number): " + UInt64.max.formatted(.number))
print("Int64.max.formatted(.number): " + Int64.max.formatted(.number))
print("UInt32.max.formatted(.number): " + UInt32.max.formatted(.number))
print("Int32.max.formatted(.number): " + Int32.max.formatted(.number))
print("UInt.max.formatted(.number): " + UInt.max.formatted(.number))
print("Int.max.formatted(.number): " + Int.max.formatted(.number))

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
print("Using NumberFormatter")
print("UInt64.max: " + formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: UInt64.max))!)
print("Int64.max: " + formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Int64.max))!)
print("UInt32.max: " + formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: UInt32.max))!)
print("Int32.max: " + formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Int32.max))!)
print("UInt.max: " + formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: UInt.max))!)
print("Int.max: " + formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Int.max))!)
```

Source Code and outputs are available at https://github.com/mtgto/ExampleNumberFormatted

Comment: If later versions returns the correct result it looks a bug that has been fixed. I am not sure what the question is really about.

Comment: I would like to know whether there is something wrong with my code or it is a bug in the Foundation.framework. If it is a Foundation.framework bug, I need to know how to make it work correctly with UInt64.max on iOS 16 and macOS 13.